# Receive Email using PHP

Tags: php, email

Does PHP have any classes to receive email? Do you know of any good resources about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I receive email and process it in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965178/how-do-i-receive-email-and-process-it-in-a-web-application)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams; Both :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [php-imap](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) library. It's very popular and stable.

Comment: Thanks @SeniorDev! :) Looks pretty damn sweet!

Answer (score 8):

I had this question too and I wanted to get emails in real time so I worked out my own solution with google app engine. I basically made a small dedicated google app engine app to receive and POST emails to my main site.

You can check out [Emailization](http://emailization.com) (a little weekend project I did to do it for you), or you this [small GAE app](https://github.com/capitao/bare-bones-receiver) that should do the trick.

I kinda explained it more on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514283/1345150).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [receive e-mail](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) in real-time(**COOL?** but have to use .appspot domain. You could off course also forward it to the .appspot domain) I would advise you to have a look at google app engine which is free to use(generous quota). You could forward the email it your webserver using [asynchronous request](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) which in turn let's you do all the cool stuf you would like it to do in PHP.

Python is pretty easy to learn especially after watching this video from Brett Slatkin explaining how to "[Developing and deploying an application on Google App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM)" and the snippets in the google app engine documentation should get you started in no time.

Comment: Also sounds like a cool project to me which I can achieve in less then 30 minutes which I find a challenge which I accept :).