# Is it possible to get own email in PHP?

Tags: php

i was wondering if its possible to get user email with PHP?

Example , i want to know my own E-Mail address when I send an e-mail to someone.

i'm finding out is it possible to do so with PHP?

I need some assist

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, what have you tried and how does your code look like right now?

Comment: If you intend to read an email inbox, see [Receive Email using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709418/receive-email-using-php)

Comment: @hank , I'm working on this :

<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: @BarryStaes, it's more towards bouncing am I right?

Comment: Ok, re-reading the question. Are you asking if you can get the visitors email-address without the user giving it to you? In that case, no.

Comment: @user3546239 yes your title confused me into thinking this was a duplicate of that question. Try rephrasing the question, right now it can be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: @hank , i want an email bounce something like authentication mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    $from = "sender id" // sender
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = 'mail from'.$from.'sender';
    $to = "receiver id";
    // send mail
    $headers = 'From: <test@test.com>' . "\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

*> i want to know my own E-Mail address when I send an e-mail to someone.*

You can not, because you have to specify it yourself in order to make it work.

- When sending emails directly from PHP using `mail()` you have to specify the "from" address yourself.
- When sending emails via a POP3 server (e.g. using the `phpmailer` class), your login account determines the "from" address.

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's `mail()` function to send emails.

More detail here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php