# Fetch inbound email data into J2ee Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, email, inbound

Anyone know the API service that help me to store email information in my J2EE application which is replied by clients.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of mail server configuration. Your mail server needs to let your Java EE know that a message has been received. Or you are using Gmail and you can configure push notifications.

See similar question here: [How to run code when you receive an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616976/how-to-run-code-when-you-receive-an-email)

Gmail push notifications: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push